# Kotlin How to fin exact word inside EditText Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

Im trying to find an exact word in the text given in a editText when the "obtenerBtn" is clicked for example if the person type in "MARIA GUADALUPE" ignore MARIA and only extract the first consonant of the next word (doesnt matter if is "GUADALUPE" the only matter is the exact word "MARIA").
If there is no MARIA just take the first consonant of the text given.

i have this and give me error "Expression '(nombre.contains("MARIA"))' of type 'Boolean' cannot be invoked as a function. The function 'invoke()' is not found"

```
    var letra3:String
        obtenerBtn.setOnClickListener {
                 
                    var nombre= nombreET.text.toString()
                    var letra3 = nombre.substring(0,1)
            if((nombre.contains("MARIA"))
                         {
                             letra3= nombre.get(5)
                    }
              else{
                    letra3 = nombre.substring(0,1)
                   }
    
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have put an extra `(` in your code `if((nombre.contains("MARIA"))` . It should be `if(nombre.contains("MARIA"))`

Comment: This seams to be the correct answer. Also i guess you should go with letra3= nombre.get(6) since the 6th character is an empty space and you want the 7th.

Comment: There is another more formal way to automatically detect the next word ?